# BeautifulSoup doesn't crawl all images on page

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, beautifulsoup

I want to crawl google images in google colab to train a tf model.

**The script**

```
doc = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=dog&tbm=isch").text, "html.parser")
all_imgs = [[image.load_img(tf.keras.utils.get_file("images",e.attrs["src"]),target_size=[90,90]),e.attrs["src"][-9:]] for e in doc.select("img")[1:]]
for e in all_imgs:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(e[0])
    plt.title(e[1])
    plt.show()
```

Explanation: 
doc is the parsed html code 
all_imgs is a list with the following format `[[img,end_of_img_link],[img,end_of_img_link],...]`

The problem is that the output is the same image over and over again.

Even if I change the url to crawl imgs of cats like `search?q=cat` it still shows the same image of a dog!

What is the problem?

EDIT: I figured out that the list consists of many copies of the same image, so the problem is the fault of BeautifulSoup not matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
All the pictures had the name "images".

Because of that the first loaded picture did not get overwritten.
I had to do: `!rm -rf /root/.keras/datasets/` in the notebook to delete the folder with the saved image.

Now I am going to name the saved picture differently.